# adding data to a JTable from another Form in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, forms, swing, netbeans

I have these two forms. One contains several buttons. The other contains two tables. On the click of one button the data is saved in a database and is then transferred to the JTable in the other form. I wrote the code through the first form only. But it doesn't work. 
Here's the code:

```
int dress1=100;
DefaultTableModel CurrPurchases=(DefaultTableModel) CurrentPurchases.getModel();
double price1=Double.parseDouble(Price1.getText());
int rows=CurrPurchases.getRowCount();
if(rows > 0){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
         CurrPurchases.removeRow(0);
    }
}
try{
    Connection connection=getConnection();
    ResultSet curprs=null;
    Statement buy1stmt=connection.createStatement();
    String Buy1Query1="Update Products set Quantity=Quantity-1 where Product_no=1;";
    String Buy1Query2="Insert into Buy values('"+Pname1.getText()+"',"+price1+");";
    buy1stmt.executeUpdate(Buy1Query1);
    buy1stmt.executeUpdate(Buy1Query2);
    dress1--;
    if(dress1==0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, This Item is Out of Stock!");
    }
    new ShoppingCart().setVisible(true);
    PreparedStatement buy2stmt=connection.prepareStatement("Select * from Buy;");
    curprs=buy2stmt.executeQuery();
    if(curprs.last()){
        CurrPurchases.addRow(new Object[]{curprs.getString(1),curprs.getDouble(2)});
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally{}
```

But this line in specific shows error(I mean underlined with a red line):

```
DefaultTableModel CurrPurchases=(DefaultTableModel) CurrentPurchases.getModel();
```

How can I add the data into that table (CurrentPurchases) in the other form?
Note: I don't want to add any button to the form, I just want the data to be displayed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's exactly the error you're facing? Is an exception? Compiling error? Hard to help you without knowing nothing about  this error.

Comment: Oh sorry! I mean it's underlined with red, it's just a kind of a warning not really an error.

Comment: What does the IDE say about this line? Why is it complaining? Missing variable? Unknown identifier? Illegal start of expression?

Comment: It says 'Cannot find symbol'...

Comment: Then I suspect this import is missing: `import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;`. Give it a try and let me know how it went :)

Comment: I've imported it but now it shows `CurrentPurchases.getModel()` underlined with red.

Comment: So is this `CurrentPurchases` a different class? I've made the assumption that it was a variable (named out of the [Java convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)) but now it seems like you need to add an import to `CurrentPurchases` class.

Comment: actually `CurrentPurchases` is the name of the jtable in the other form. So what should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments section:

> `CurrentPurchases.getModel()` underlined with red. Actually
>   `CurrentPurchases` is the name of the jtable in the other form. So
>   what should I do now?

I understand your problem now. You're trying to access a variable defined in a form from another form directly. That's why the compiler is complaining. You'll need to create a public getter to this `CurrentPurchases` in order to access it from other class. Something like this:

```
public JTable getCurrentPurchasesTable() {
    return this.CurrentPurchases;
}
```

Then make this change:

```
DefaultTableModel CurrPurchases= (DefaultTableModel) otherFormVariable.getCurrentPurchasesTable().getModel();
```

Of course you'll need a reference to the other form (I called it `otherFormVariable` in the example) in order to get the table as you wish.

---

An off-topic tip:

- Always try to follow [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf). It makes people talk the same language.

---

### Edit: implementation examples

Well as you're new to Java (welcome to this world :P) I'll give you two possible implementation examples.

First off let's say you have 2 forms as follows:

- `Form1`: here is placed your table.
- `Form2`: here you can add a new    record to your DB and the previous
  table.

#### Example 1: Giving public access to Form1's table

The first way is the one you're trying. To make it work in this way you'll need do something like this:

```
public class Form1 extends JDialog {

    JTable currentPurchases;
    JButton addRecordButton;

    private initComponents() {
        addRecordButton = new JButton("Add record");
        addRecord.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Form2 form2 = new Form2();
                form2.setForm1(this);
                form2.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        ... // init the table and other components
    }

    public JTable getCurrentPurchasesTable() {
        return this.currentPurchases;
    }
}

public class Form2 extends JDialog {

    Form1 form1; // this variable will keep reference to a Form1 instance
    JButton saveRecordButton;

    private void initComponents() {
        saveRecordButton = new JButton("Save record");
        saveRecordButton .addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) form1.getCurrentPurchasesTable().getModel();
                // add new rocord to the model
            }
        };
        ... // init the other components

    }

    public void setForm1(Form1 f) {
        this.form1 = f;
    }

}
```

#### Example 2: Setting a TableModel to Form2

This second way is about setting a `TableModel` to the `Form2` object. This way you don't need public access to your table anymore. It should be something like this:

```
public class Form1 extends JDialog {

    JTable currentPurchases;
    JButton addRecordButton;

    private initComponents() {
        addRecordButton = new JButton("Add record");
        addRecord.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Form2 form2 = new Form2();
                form2.setTableModel(currentPurchases.getModel());
                form2.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        ... // init the table and other components
    }
}

public class Form2 extends JDialog {

    TableModel model; // this variable will keep reference to a TableModel instance
    JButton saveRecordButton;

    private void initComponents() {
        saveRecordButton = new JButton("Save record");
        saveRecordButton .addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                // add new rocord to the model:
                ((DefaultTableModel)model).addRow(...);                    
            }
        };
        ... // init the other components

    }

    public void setTableModel(TableModel m) {
        this.model = m;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this, where should I exactly enter the public getter?

Comment: No worries, no need to apologize :) Let's say you have `Form1` where your table is placed. There you should add public access to this table. Now you have another class `Form2` where you're adding data. So this second one has to mantain a reference to `Form1` and then it will be able to call `Form1.getCurrentPurchasesTable().getModel();`. Let me know if it's clear enough :) @LuluLala

Comment: Not sure if I did it in the right way but I just followed your instructions and it shows a warning: `non-static method getCurrentPurchasesTable() cannot be referenced from a static context`...where should I type that public getter, I mean at which line or page?

Comment: @mKorbel my magic ball lost connection for a couple of hours but now I think it's working again :P @LuluLala the new error you're getting is because you don't keep any reference to a `Form1` object. Please see updated answer. I've included two examples of implementation. Hope these be helpful and can lead you in the right way :)